# PyRun_SimpleString call cause memory corruption?

Tags: python, c++, embed

I am trying to use Python in C++ and have the following code. I intended to parse and do sys.path.append on a user input path. It looks like the call to PyRun_SimpleString caused some sort of spillage into a private class var of the class. How did this happen? I have tried various buffer size 50, 150, 200, and it did not change the output.

```
class Myclass
{
    ...
    private:
        char *_modName;
        char *_modDir;
};
Myclass::Myclass()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString((char *)"sys.path.append('/home/userA/Python')");
}
Myclass::init()
{
    // this function is called before Myclass::test()
    // a couple other python funcitons are called as listed below. 
    // PyString_FromString, PyImport_Import, PyObject_GetAttrString, PyTuple_New, PyTuple_SetItem, PyObject_CallObject, PyDict_GetItemString
}
Myclass::test()
{
    char buffer[150];
    char *strP1 = (char *)"sys.path.append('";
    char *strP2 = (char *)"')";
    strcpy (buffer, strP1);
    strcat (buffer, _modDir);
    strcat (buffer, strP2);
    printf("Before %s\n", _modDir);
    printf("Before %s\n", _modName);
    PyRun_SimpleString(buffer);
    printf("After %s\n", _modName);
}
```

Here is the output. FYI I'm using a,b,c,d,f for illustration purpose only. It almost fills like PyRun_SimpleString(buffer) stick the end of buffer into _modName.

```
Before /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
Before ffffff
After cc/ddd'
```

Comment: How is _modName initialised? Is the memory to which it is initialised free'ed and reused in Python?

Comment: Since you are using C++, may I suggest using the `string` type? It is far less error prone and you don't need to worry about buffer sizes and de-allocation. When you need to pass in a `(char*)` you can just call the `c_str()` method built into `string`.

Comment: _modName is retrieved from parsing the return dict of a python script    _modName = PyString_AsString  (PyDict_GetItemString(pValue, (char*)"modName"));

Comment: Should I have saved the content returned from PyString_AsString() somewhere else before calling PyRun_SimpleString()?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Klamer Schutte for hinting in the correct direction.
The DECRF in my code was the culprit. Being unfamilar with how reference works, I guess. The DECREF call released pValue together with it the content pointed by _modName. A guess a more beginner quesiton would be, should I have added a Py_INCREF(pValue) after _modName assignment?

```
_modName = PyString_AsString (PyDict_GetItemString(pValue, (char*)"modName"));
Py_DECREF(pValue);
```